# Do hyperbolic rotations/lorentz transformations behave like this or did I implement them wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, noneuclidean-geometry

(not sure if this belongs here, in StackOverflow or in the physics StackExchange, but I believe my issue is with the math so I'm posting here.)

I've recently been reading the book [Dichronauts](https://www.gregegan.net/DICHRONAUTS/DICHRONAUTS.html) by Greg Egan and I decided to make a little simulation to understand the world more. The book takes place in a universe where the distance metric is $d^2=\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2 - \Delta u^2$ where $u$ is basically just the Z coordinate (named as such due to the fact that it's a second *timelike* dimension, and $u$ is the letter after $t$). This has the effect of stretching out space as one rotates. I'll be simplifying to $d^2=\Delta x^2-\Delta u^2$ since my simulation only uses 2 dimensions. Doing this in both directions creates a hyperbolic rotation, which is the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\theta & -\sinh\theta \\ \sinh\theta & \cosh\theta\end{bmatrix}$

which looks like this:

[Hyperbolic rotation in both directions](https://i.imgur.com/JlMhpTr.gif)

From what I understand, this is rotating in two timelike directions at once. In the story, however, they're rotating in 2 spacelike and 1 timelike direction (or, since we're in 2D, I've reduced it to 1 spacelike and 1 timelike.) This is what I'm unsure about; I believe the matrix looks like this:

$\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta & -\sinh\theta \\ \cos\theta & \cosh\theta\end{bmatrix}$

thereby rotating $\hat{\imath}$ by $\theta$ and hyperbolically rotating $\hat{\jmath}$ by $\theta$. This looks like this:

[Partial Hyperbolic Rotation](https://i.imgur.com/UfDO4ZN.gif)

This seems consistent with the transformations described in the book (and on Greg Egan's website) but I'm still confused about a few things. I thought that a hyperbola (which I've shown in purple) should be rotationally invariant, however when rotating it, it appears to stretch into a set of straight lines.

[Hyperbola stretching into straight lines](https://i.imgur.com/fxUdzvi.gif)

Did I do my math wrong or is this just what rotational invariance looks like when we try to project this space into a euclidean one?

Also, in the book rotation by more than 45 degrees is impossible. I expected that as I increase the angle, things would just get more stretched out endlessly, similar to how doing purely hyperbolic rotation actually never rotates more than 45 degrees, just stretching things forever. However, when I try that here, space just sort of flips endlessly.

[Flipping behavior at greater than 45 degrees](https://i.imgur.com/jIkEnOk.gif)

Is this just an artifact of how I'm using hyperbolic rotations to represent Lorentz transformations here or is this something wrong with the matrix I'm using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in both directions".

Comment: doing a hyperbolic rotation in both directions (i.e. to both i hat and j hat)

Comment: It's a lot easier for me to understand an explanation if it doesn't use the same term I didn't understand to explain what it means.

Comment: the matrix is there. I was just talking about using sinh and cosh in place of sin and cos in the rotation matrix before I went to the case that i care about (using sin and cos only in the left of the matrix, and sinh and cosh in the right.) I am asking about whether that is an accurate way to do lorentz transformations or whether I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer a while ago but forgot to post it until now. The correct matrix is:

$\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\theta & \sinh\theta \\ \sinh\theta & \cosh\theta\end{bmatrix}$

which exhibits the right properties.